# How does this short scissors paper rock logic work

Tags: python

I am trying to code a scissors paper rock game in Tkinter, looking for a shorter alternative.

Here is the jist. Human picks rock, paper, scissors, and so does the computer. Each option is added to a number. Rock = 0. Paper = 1, Scissors =2.

Now here is the problem. How does this logic work for checking who won?

`whoWon = (computer choice - human choice) % 3`

Answer (score 1):

% is a modulo operator meaning it returns the remainder so

```
...
-3 % 3 = -1 r 0
-2 % 3 = -1 r 1
-1 % 3 = -1 r 2
0 % 3 = 0 r 0
1 % 3 = 0 r 1
2 % 3 = 0 r 2
3 % 3 = 1 r 0
...
```

so for the 3*3 combinations we get the following

```
0,0 = 0 % 3 = 0
0,1 = -1 % 3 = 2
0,2 = -2 % 3 = 1
1,0 = 1 % 3 = 1
1,1 = 0 % 3 = 0
1,2 = -1 % 3 = 2
2,0 = 2 % 3 = 2
2,1 = 1 % 3 = 1
2,2 = 3 % 3 = 0
```

modulo is commonly used to divide something into n sets (`% n`)

So you can see if both players choose the same item the value us `x-x % 3 = 0` or a tie, otherwise it returns 1 or 2 depending on the sequence

Answer (score 0):

You can figure it out by looking at the 9 possible combinations:

```
Computer     Human       (computer - human) % 3
0 Rock       0 Rock                0        0 # Draw
0 Rock       1 Paper              -1        2 # Human
0 Rock       2 Scissors           -2        1 # Computer
1 Paper      0 Rock                1        1 # Computer
1 Paper      1 Paper               0        0 # Draw
1 Paper      2 Scissors           -1        2 # Human
2 Scissors   0 Rock                2        2 # Human
2 Scissors   1 Paper               1        1 # Computer
2 Scissors   2 Scissors            0        0 # Draw
```

The difference is 0 when both players select the same value.

The difference is -1 or 2 when the human wins, which converts to 2 when module 3 is applied:

```
-1%3 = 2
 2%3 = 2
```

The difference is 1 or -2 when the computer wins, which converts to 1 when modulo 3 is applied:

```
 1%3 = 1
-2%3 = 1
```

*Note that this works in Python because its modulo operation is based on the [mathematical definition](https://torstencurdt.com/tech/posts/modulo-of-negative-numbers/). Many other languages, such as Javascript apply the sign of the numerator to the modulo between absolute values resulting in different results when numerator and denominator have different signs, which may be visually pleasing but is mathematically incorrect.*